# Add button on Game SurfaceView using XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, surfaceview, android-button

I have a game surface for playing a game. Now I need to use some button on my image. But I need to use XML layout file for adding the button on the game view. I used XML layout, but I'm getting

```
Error Inflating class com.name.company.surfaceview.GameView
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GameView GameView;
    Button btnStart;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //for no title
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //setContentView(new GameView(this));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GameView = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.gameView);
         btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    }
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <view class="com.name.company.surfaceview$GameView"
        android:id="@+id/gameView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnStart"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="button" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Java` code does not seem to have a problem. **But** , may be the problem with your `XML` file. Replace your `XML` file with this one:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<view class="com.name.company.surfaceview$GameView"
    android:id="@+id/gameView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnStart"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If this code did not work, then the problem is with the `class` `com.name.company.surfaceview$GameView`. Try again the same code but put the `button` item above the `class` item. I hope it helps

Comment: It's not working. If i remove view from xml and remove this line from java Game = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.gameView); the button is displaying..But when i include GameView it's not working.

Comment: Make sure that both height and width are `match_parent` not `fill_parent`

Comment: @user3351727 I have changed the layout to be `LinearLayout` and removed the `gravity` from the button. Try it again

Comment: It's not working..Getting this error: 02-27 21:32:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(623): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.name.company.surfaceview$GameView

Comment: I have the same problem and I cannot manage to find a solution even though I've been spending the last day searching on the Internet. Can you please tell me how did you manage to fix it?